# Google Accounts/History

Tags: google-chrome

So I have a two Gmail/Google Accounts, one for personal use and one for college. Let’s say I search up Google Slides on my college account then, I open a new tab switch to my home account and search up something like video games or YouTube. Will the search history from my home account be visible or "transfer" to my college account?